# Serve a web application from another one

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a web application which uses the identity server and I want to create a separate thin central login application. I want to deploy only one application to the server with that login application. Can I add it as a service to my identity server web app? Is there a way to do like below? If there is, how can I do that?

(First web project which wanted to deploy)

Project.IdentityServer.Web

(Second web project which wanted to serve in the first one)

Project.IdentityServer.CentralLogin.Web

```
services.AddCentralLoginApp();
```

Comment: Projects have to be deployed separately. You cannot deploy one web app that "contains" another web app. Deploy both individually, and then configure the URL to the supporting app via config.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 separate web applications (one of which is acting as an authentication server), there's no direct way to add a service (through DI) to the application that does not do authentication.

You can configure the web application that doesn't do authentication to direct to a front end representing the authentication server's login page though. If you set up the identity server to hold the client credentials of the web app (the client application), you can get the identity and access token for any user of the client application to use for authentication by going through the OpenID Connect flow.